pdfkit python taking too long - wkhtmltopdf
I have to create from heavy HTML file(170MB)
but pdfkit.from_string / pdfkit.from_file this line taking too long
pdfkit.from_string(input=f.read(), output_path=file_path, options=options)
options = {
            'page-size': 'B3',
            'margin-top': '0.25in',
            'margin-right': '0.50in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.25in',
            'margin-left': '0.50in',
            'encoding': "UTF-8",
            "enable-local-file-access": "",
            'lowquality': True,
          }

is there any other option for it
There are many images in pdf how can I improve it's performance
